# Click follow button if possible and close tab after checking/following Instagramm with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, instagram, webautomation

I tried with xpath, find by name etc. but it always doesnt find the follow button i already made it sign in accept cookie and all that i can give the code i got in discord i dont wanna do it here because of a certain reason, Thanks for any help

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/span/span[1]/button').click()
```

ik its deprecated btw.
Brave TheRealChicken#4398
I tried it at other threads on this forum but they dont seem to work

Comment: The above is a snip from the whole code i wrote for trying it

Comment: Still needing help :p Hassan might help me tho, just for anyone wondering code below didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using absolute xpath which is not preferred because a minor change in website renders your code ineffective. Always try to use relative xpath.

Anyway, try this code, it will work.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//main[@role='main']//button/div[contains(string(), 'Follow')]").click()
```

Change the text "Follow" as per what you see in your language on instagram. For german language, the code should be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//main[@role='main']//button/div[contains(string(), 'Folgen')]").click()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242744/discussion-on-answer-by-hassan-sabir-click-follow-button-if-possible-and-close-t).